# Preimage of a null set by a non-monotonic absolutely continuous function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ be an absolutely continuous function.

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that, for any null set $N \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1} (N) \cap \{ t \in [0,1] \mid f'(t) \neq 0 \}$ is a null set.

In the literature I found several references showing that, when $f$ is nondecreasing, then the result is true. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249483/lebesgue-measurability-of-subset-of-the-preimage-of-a-measurable-set-under-incre) for example (and references therein).

However I was unable to adapt the proof to the non-monotonic case. Furthermore, to try to construct a counterexample, I found an absolutely continuous function which is nowhere monotone ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4160092/existence-of-nowhere-monotone-absolutely-continuous-function) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval)). Unfortunately I was not able to go any further.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Never worked with absolute continuity before, was just skimming the wiki on it.  Could using the fact that you can write it as the difference of two monotonic nondecreasing absolutely continuous functions help?

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your answer and your time. Actually I also tried your approach but, unfortunately, as far as I know, the preimage of a sum IS NOT the sum of the preimages in general. As a consequence, I was not able to conclude with this approah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true, but the proof is not simple.
Let $I=[0,1]$, $E:=f^{-1}\left(  N\right)$, and $E^{\ast}:=\left\{  x\in E:\,\left\vert f^{\prime}\left(  x\right)
\right\vert >0\right\}  $.

We need to prove that $\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  E^{\ast
}\right)  =0$. For every integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let
$$
E_{k}^{\ast}:=\left\{  x\in E^{\ast}:\,\left\vert f\left(  x\right)  -f\left(
y\right)  \right\vert \geq\frac{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }{k}\text{ for all
}y\in\left(  x-\tfrac{1}{k},x+\tfrac{1}{k}\right)  \cap I\right\}  .
$$
Note that
$$
E^{\ast}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{k}^{\ast}.
$$
Hence, if we fix $k$ and we let $F:=J\cap E_{k}^{\ast}$, where $J$ is an interval of
length less than $\frac{1}{k}$, then to prove that $\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  E^{\ast
}\right)  =0$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  F\right)  =0$.

Since $\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  f\left(  E\right)  \right)  =0$ and $F\subset
E$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we may find a sequence of intervals $\left\{
J_{n}\right\}  $ such that
$$
f\left(  F\right)  \subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}J_{n},\quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  J_{n}\right)  <\varepsilon.
$$
Let $E_{n}:=f^{-1}\left(  J_{n}\right)  \cap F$. Since $\left\{
E_{n}\right\}  $ covers $F$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{o}^{1}\left(  F\right)   &  \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}%
\mathcal{L}_{o}^{1}\left(  E_{n}\right)  \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup_{x,y\in
E_{n}}\left\vert x-y\right\vert \\
&  \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}k\sup_{x,y\in E_{n}}\left\vert f\left(  x\right)
-f\left(  y\right)  \right\vert,
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact that $E_{n}\subset J\cap E_{k}^{\ast}.$ Since
$f\left(  E_{n}\right)  \subset J_{n}$, we have
$$
\sup_{x,y\in E_{n}}\left\vert f\left(  x\right)  -f\left(  y\right)
\right\vert \leq\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  J_{n}\right)  ,
$$
and so
$$\mathcal{L}_{o}^{1}\left(  F\right) \le
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}k\sup_{x,y\in E_{n}}\left\vert f\left(  x\right)
-f\left(  y\right)  \right\vert\leq k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}^{1}\left(  J_{n}\right)
<k\varepsilon.
$$
It now suffices to let $\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I found a few days ago a similar proof in the paper "A general chain rule for derivatives and the change of variables formula for the Lebesgue integral" by Serrin and Varberg in 1969 (see the proof of Theorem 1 in that paper). Maybe you have been inspired by the same paper? In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. It’s taken from there. Serrin was my Ph.D. advisor!

Comment: Ha! That's a small world! :)